# Health check response lacks .json extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-monitoring

I have implemented a health check with a ResponseWriter:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck("My Health Check", new MyHealthCheck(aVariable));

app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
{
    ResponseWriter = WriteHealthCheckResponse
});

private static Task WriteHealthCheckResponse(HttpContext httpContext, HealthReport result){
httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

var json = new JObject(
    new JProperty("status", result.Status.ToString()),
    new JProperty("results", new JObject(result.Entries.Select(pair =>
        new JProperty(pair.Key, new JObject(
            new JProperty("status", pair.Value.Status.ToString()),
            new JProperty("description", pair.Value.Description)))))));
return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
    json.ToString(Formatting.Indented));}
```

I was expecting it to return a *health.json* file, however it returns just *health*. The browser doesn't recognize the file without an extension and doesn't want to open it, therefor I want to control the filename.

How can I control the file name of the response?

**Update:**

When the health check passes, I now **do** get a *health.json* file (which can be opened).
However, when the health check fails, I get a *health* file.

Trying to download the fail *health* message (health without .json extension), I only get a partial download which can be opened, but stays empty.

So, what's wrong with the non happy flow in this code:

```
public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)){
var isHealthy = false;

try
{
    var executionResult = _service.ExecuteExample();
    isHealthy = executionResult != null;
}
catch
{
    //This should not throw an exception.
}

HealthCheckResult healthResult = isHealthy 
    ? HealthCheckResult.Healthy("The service is responding as expected.") 
    : HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("There is a problem with the service.");

return Task.FromResult(healthResult);}
```

Comment: _"Of course the browser doesn't recognize the file without an extension."_ - What is your expectation? What do you mean "doesn't recognize"? Do you mean it doesn't prompt you to download the JSON response?

Comment: Added to question: by controlling the file name, the browser can recognize the file type and directly open the file.

Comment: My browser will happily display JSON for me. Are you sure that the Content-Type header is taking effect?

Comment: and you can just add the .json extension to your browser URL to tell the browser what to expect. This works in Chrome

Comment: You correctly set the `Content-Type` of the response to `application/json`. How the browser handles JSON is outside your control but it may be affected by the URL (it ends in `.json`) especially on Windows where extensions map to applications. However, the concept of _file extensions_ is not part HTTP. That being said you can use the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to instruct the browser to save the file using a specified file name. However, that is normally used with downloads and not JSON responses.

Comment: I know, but why does the exact same message work for HealthCheckResult.Healthy but not for HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy? I both instructed to write the same, valid, .json file, but only HealthCheckResult.Healthy succeeds in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @MichelvanEngelen: It is not easy to answer that question. The general problem in your question is that the browser doesn't handle `application/json` as you expect. When using Internet Explorer 11 this depends on how Windows is configured. You can associate both media types (like `application/json`) and extensions with applications so you may get different results on different Windows installations. Summing up: this is a browser issue. However, your update about when the health check fails could be a server issue. I would definitely remove the `catch`. Also, use F12 to see the actual response.

Answer (score 1):

My code runs just fine on my co workers machine.
In the end it seems Internet Explorer 11 is the culprit. In Chrome it just works..

**Update and solution:**
Thanks to Martin Liversage I found the answer. 
By using the F12 developer tools in IE, I found that the HTTP Status Code on unhealthy is *503 Service Unavailable*. This prevents IE from downloading the .json result.

Now, this can easily be fixed by setting the HealthCheckOptions:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
{
    ResultStatusCodes = { [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = 200 }, 
    ResponseWriter = WriteHealthCheckResponse
});
```

Use this if you integrate health checks on basis of the contents of the .json file. Don't when you only look at HTTP Status.

Comment: This could be because IE downloads the result of the request in its failed state when there is nothing to serve, I've also noticed this where it's actually downloading a file with the same name as the URL path, in this case `healthcheck`. Your successful response returns a file and so the file is what's downloaded, `healthcheck.json`